# How can I pass this JavaScript CodeWars challenge?

Tags: javascript

In this challenge I have to replace every `"WUB"`in the string with a space. If there is more than one `"WUB"` in a row then I have to replace all of them with a single space. For example, entering `"WUBAPPLEWUBWUBBANANAWUBWUBWUBCARROT"` would return `"APPLE BANANA CARROT"`.

Also I have to get rid of heading and trailing spaces at the beginning and end of the string. I was wondering how I could change my code to pass these requirements, I'm still pretty new to JavaScript. Thanks.

```
function songDecoder(song){
  var regex = /wub/gi;
  song = song.toLowerCase().replace(regex, ' ')
  return song.toUpperCase()
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's essentially asking for a solution to a code challenge on a website, which defeats the website's purpose and provides little to no value for future readers.

Comment: I wanted to see if my code could be modified to work, not sure why you want to close this question. Just trying to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You're on right track all you need to do is add a quantifier to match more than one `WUB` in continuation, and you can also avoid first converting to lowercase and than converting back to uppercase after match as we are using `i` flag which will take care of case insensitivity

```
(?:wub)+
```

[image]

```js
let str = "WUBAPPLEWUBWUBBANANAWUBWUBWUBCARROT"

function songDecoder(song){
  var regex = /(?:wub)+/gi;
  song = song.replace(regex, ' ')
  return song.trim()
}

console.log(songDecoder(str))
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Can you please explain the syntax behind /(?:wub)+gi

Comment: @DragonG `(?:wub)+` this means match `wub` one or more time, so it consider `wubwub` as single match whereas if you use `wub` the `wubwub` this will be considered two matches, `i` flag stands for case insensitivity

Comment: If you want could you explain the syntax more in depth (by each character)? Thanks.

Comment: @DragonG have added a graphic representation which explains everything about regex i used, you can see

Answer (score 0):

As you are new so you need to understand the symbols of using regular expression:

**g modifier:** global. All matches (don't return after first match)

**i modifier:** insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])

In your case though `i` is immaterial as you dont capture `[a-zA-Z]`.

For input like **`!@#$?`** if `g` modifier is not there regex will return first match `!`[**See here**](https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/55).

If `g` is there it will return the whole or whatever it can match. [**See here**](https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/56)

```
let var  = "WUBAPPLEWUBWUBBANANAWUBWUBwubCARROT";
function songDecoder(song){
  var regex = /(?:wub)+/gi;
  song = song.replace(regex, ' ')
  return song.trim()
}
```

alert(songDecoder(str));

Comment: What does the : in /(?:wub)+/gi do? Thanks.

Comment: regexp? 
A regular expression regexp followed by ? matches a string of zero or one occurrences of strings that would match regexp. 

wub matches the characters
 gi matches the characters  gi literally (case insensitive)

For more details see here https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man5/regexp.5.asp